# Is there a way to log everything from console.log in an Electron app using electon-log?

Tags: node.js, electron

I already have a ton of console.log statement thru out the main process of my Electron app, is there a way to send all of those to electron-log or another log that can be access after the app is packaged? I was going to go thru and add `log.error` thru out the script, but hoping there is a better way.

```
console.log('this error', error)
log.error('this error:', error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
console.log = function(){
   ...your code...
};
```

Can be an idea?

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb, was overthinking it, thanks. I think I'll use a different name for the function though and just replace all the `console.log` with one log function that will do both, thanks!